# проблема при работе с open server , выдает ошибку при обращении к mysql

Tags: mysql, openserver

пишет ошибку при нажатии кнопки phpшной для обращения в БД. 
Warning: include(C:\OSER\OSPanel\domains\localhost\organizer\tabs): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\OSER\OSPanel\domains\localhost\organizer\index.php on line 171

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'tabs/' for inclusion (include_path='.') in C:\OSER\OSPanel\domains\localhost\organizer\index.php on line 171

не понимаю в чем дело, что только не перепробовал но она все равно вылезает

Comment: в какой-то момент она резко появилась и стало невозможно работать на локалхосте с опенсервером

Comment: Почему-то интуиция подсказывает мне, что проблема с правами, а не с базой данных

Comment: что делать с правами?

Comment: Надо настраивать

Comment: помогите, как настроить их , у меня 7 винда

Comment: Поставьте base_path в апаче со значением none

Comment: "Поставьте base_path в апаче со значением none" - и что это даст? И где это нужно поставить в open server? не могу найти